# Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with probability function $P(X=x)=\frac2{3^x}$ for $x = 1,2,3,\ldots$ What is the probability that $X$ is even?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with probability function $P(X=x) = \frac{2}{3^x}$ for $x = 1,2,3,\ldots$

What is the probability that $X$ is even?

I have:
$$\frac2{3^2}+\frac2{3^4}+\frac2{3^6}+\ldots$$ which is a geometric series of the form
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^n$$
where $a = \frac29$ and $r=\frac19$.

Then I used the formula for finding the sum of a geometric series to find the sum/probability
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^n &= \frac{a}{1-r} \\
 &= \frac{\frac29}{1-\frac19} \\
 &= \frac{2/9}{8/9} = \frac28 = \frac14
\end{align}

Correct?

Comment: Yes, the summation is correct.

Comment: Don't deface your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Following @Henry, your approach is just fine. For variety, here is yet another. In *trinary*, you have $$0.020202020\ldots$$ Is it easy to see that three ($10$ in trinary) times this is $$0.20202020\ldots$$ and then summing the two gives $$0.222222222\ldots$$ which is $1$. Therefore four times your number is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct and is a reasonable approach.

Here is another:

- you have here $\Pr(X=2n) = \frac13 \Pr(X=2n-1)$ for all integer $n$,
- so the probability of $X$ being even is a third of the probability of $X$ being not even,
- making the probability of $X$ being even equal to $\frac14$.